# Forcing CSS inline-block display to new line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use CSS inline blocks as an alternative to creating tables of logos.

Unfortunatley, the logos are not flowing down to the next line but being placed underneath each other (e.g. see arrow in example below)

[image]

My code currently looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TEST</title>
<style type="text/css">
.gallery{
    display:block;
}
.thumbnail{
    display:inline-block;
    border:0px;
    float:left;
    max-width:250px !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    margin-left: 1cm;
    margin-right: 1cm;
    margin-top: 1cm;
    margin-bottom: 1cm;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<img class="gallery thumbnail" src=“X” alt=“Z” />
<img class="gallery thumbnail" src=“X” alt=“Z” />
<img class="gallery thumbnail" src=“X” alt=“Z”  />
<img class="gallery thumbnail" src=“X” alt=“Z”  />
<img class="gallery thumbnail" src=“X” alt=“Z”  />
<img class="gallery thumbnail" src=“X” alt=“Z”  />
<img class="gallery thumbnail" src=“X” alt=“Z”  />
<img class="gallery thumbnail" src=“X” alt=“Z” />

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `float: left;` from .thumbnail

```
.gallery{
    display:block;
}
.thumbnail{
    display:inline-block;
    border:0px;
    max-width:250px !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    margin-left: 1cm;
    margin-right: 1cm;
    margin-top: 1cm;
    margin-bottom: 1cm;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> float:left;
> ```

Floating rules override the inline-block rules. Don't float them.

Comment: Yep, as stated in [Relationships between 'display', 'position', and 'float'](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)